# SVN timeout (E175002) when checking out files, but can browser the repo ok

Tags: svn, visualsvn, visualsvn-server

I'm trying to connect my new machine to my SVN repo. I can connect ok, and even browse the repo, but as soon as I try to checkout the files onto my laptop (Macbook Pro, Mavericks) I get the following error:

```
Cannot check out from svn: svn: E175002: Operation timed out
svn: E175002: OPTIONS request failed on '<my repo>'
```

I'm trying to use PHPStorm 7, but I also get the same error from Dreamweaver CC and svnX (Dreamweaver doesn't have a browse option, so it just goes straight to the error).

I can't remember having any trouble setting this up on my old machine (also a Macbook Pro, Mountain Lion, then Mavericks upgrade).

The SVN server is VisualSVN, running on an old XP machine. I'm using the IP address to connect, which is our external IP and connects via port forwarding on the router. My external server can connect and checkout etc. with no problems. I can also use the VisualSVN web interface to connect and browse.

I've spent a bit of time googling, but can't find any clues, so I'm a bit stumped.

Comment: Please specify the exact and complete error message and what's logged to VisualSVN Server's log.

Answer (score 1):

- Make sure that you use correct URL to VisualSVN Server repositories.
- Check what's logged to [VisualSVN Server log](http://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00028/).
- If you have any proxy server between your machine and VisualSVN Server, remember to setup proxy settings.

Comment: It's definitely the correct URL, as it works from our remote server with TortoiseSVN. There's no proxy server, so nothing to set up. Nothing shows up in the VisualSVN logs, but it's the free version, so I can't enable the Operational or Access logging unfortunately.